# Minimizing the sum of cosines of non-obtuse angles formed by $n\geq4$ concurrent lines in $3$D space

Tags: geometry, optimization, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose I have two lines in $3$D space passing through the origin. The smallest angle formed between them would be between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Minimizing the cosine of this angle we'll get $\cos {(\pi/2)}=0$.

For $3$ lines there will be in total $3$ angles between them. Let's again suppose these angles are between $0$ and $\pi/2$. The minimum of the sum of the cosines of these angles will be $0$; when each vector is $pi/2$ away from the other two.

But for $4$ lines and beyond, every angle cannot be made $\pi/2$ in $3$D space. I need to find the minimum of the sum of cosines for $n$ number of lines.

For example, let's take the case of $4$ lines. There are $6$ angles formed between them. I tried to minimize the sum of cosines numerically and got the value as $1$. This is the case when $3$ lines are perpendicular, and the fourth vector is along  one of those $3$. For $5$ lines, the minimum is $2$; lines double up in two of the axis and one vector perpendicular to them. For $6$ lines, the minimum is $3$; two lines along each axis.

From numerical results, it seems that the minimum will be when the lines are along the $3$D axes, but I don't yet have a proof for this. Can proof be made through induction? Kindly help out in any way possible.

EDIT (27/10/21)

Take the case of $4$ lines. We can imagine them as vectors pointing from the origin to the surface of a unit sphere, say $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$. Moreover, since we are only concerned with the smallest angle between each and every pair, we can take all the vectors to lie in the same octant of the sphere.
Now, we want to minimize the sum $$\cos(\theta_{12})+\cos(\theta_{13})+\cos(\theta_{14})+\cos(\theta_{23})+\cos(\theta_{24})+\cos(\theta_{34})$$
$$=(\cos(\theta_{12})+\cos(\theta_{13})+\cos(\theta_{14}))+\cos(\theta_{23})+\cos(\theta_{24})+\cos(\theta_{34})$$
where the terms in the bracket is equal to $$v_1\cdot(v_2+v_3+v_4)$$ Since $v_2,v_3,v_4$ lies in an octant, their sum would also lie in that octant. The previous dot product is minimized when $v_1$ is along one of the axes. We can repeat the same argument for every vector and see that for minimizing the sum of cosines, every vector should be along the axes.

I believe the above argument holds for any $n$. Once we know the lines are along the axes, I guess it's easy enough to derive a form for the minimal value. Is there anything wrong with my argument? How to formalize this proof if correct?

Comment: Not a solution but potentially useful: Note that the angles don't change by stretching the vectors. So we may assume they lie on $S^2$ and the minimization thus becomes:
$$
\min_{(x_j)_{j=1,...,n}}\sum_{i,j} \langle x_i, x_j \rangle
$$

Comment: $a_i^2+b_i^2+c_i^2=1$, $a_ia_j+b_ib_j+c_ic_j\geq 0$, $\sum_{i<j}(a_ia_j+b_ib_j+c_ic_j)={\rm min}$

Comment: Every additional vector adds at least 1.

Comment: @Moti Yes. 7,8 and 9 vectors add 2 to the minimum value

Comment: Isn't it: _The smallest angle formed between them would be between 0 and **π**. Minimizing the cosine of this angle we'll get cos(**pi**)= **-1** ._ for 2 vectors??

Comment: @f5r5e5d No, The smallest angle would be Pi/2 if you extend the vectors in both directions

Comment: Then perhaps you mean: _Suppose I have two **lines through a point (the origion)** in 3D space._ since vectors do have direction

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Let $S_{k,min}$ is minimum cosine sum for $k$ vectors without blunt angles. $S_{k+1}=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k+1} \cos\alpha_{ij}=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\sum_{1\leq i<j \leq k+1, i,j\neq m}\cos\alpha_{ij}\geq \frac{k+1}{k-1}S_{k,min}$. If we knew that all $S_{k,min}$ are integers then we could prove that $S_{n,min}=\lfloor\frac{n^2-3n+3}{6}\rfloor$ by induction.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272692/the-minimum-of-a-sum-of-absolute-values-of-inner-products-in-mathbbrd/273028#273028 for a partial answer

Comment: I like your most recent edit, redefining to work with vectors in the first octant. What you did looks good too. I think that for a proof by induction, the easiest approach would be to show that your claim holds for n = 3, 3k, 3k+1, and 3k+2 for any positive integer k.